# How to get values of :var arguments in ob-shell assigned when tangling?

Tags: org-mode, tangle

When I run the code bellow directly in orgmode it outputs the correct result

```
#+begin_src sh :var value=1234 :tangle a.sh
echo "value  = " $value
#+end_src
```

> value = 1234

But when tangled, it generates file a.sh with only

> echo "value  = " $value

How do I get the assignment "value=1234" in a.sh ?

Answer (score 4):

In my emacs 25.1.1. + org version 9.0.4 the tangled a.out file correctly contains

```
value='1234'
echo "value  = " $value
```

I have used these kind of functions and tangling extensively and for a long time, so I can only guess that you may be running a very old version of org mode. Try to update it from http://orgmode.org/elpa/ using the package manager.